# How to Retrieve the Download Link for Large Video Files

Tags: java, video, google-drive-api

I would like to retrieve the download link for large video files. I have no problems with small video files but with large videos, the response from the server is that the file

"exceeds the maximum file size that Google can scan"

I want to use the link as the source to a `video` tag. But because that link gives me the error, I can't use it.

I'm using the `Java SDK` and I'm using `File.getWebContentLink()` to get the link. I've tried `getDownloadLink()` but that one doesn't even work.

Basically, is there anyway I can get the download link for large video files?

Answer (score 0):

getWebContentLink() is designed for interactive users (browsers).

Instead, at the raw API level you'll want to use File.get with alt=Media *AND* also set the acknowledgeAbuse flag if you initially get returned the 'Google can't scan'. Read more on [downloading files here](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/manage-downloads#using_altmedia) and the [abuse flag here](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/files/get#request).

In the Java client library, it'd look something like this:

```
String fileId = "0BwwA4oUTeiV1UVNwOHItT0xfa2M";
OutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
driveService.files().get(fileId)
    .set("acknowledgeAbuse", true)
    .executeMediaAndDownloadTo(outputStream);
```

Disclaimer, I haven't compiled the above.

**Note:** Do not use the `.../host/id` method mentioned in the other answer - that method is [deprecated and scheduled to stop serving content](http://googleappsdeveloper.blogspot.com/2015/08/deprecating-web-hosting-support-in.html) by end of August, 2016 (this year)

Answer (score -1):

Try using https://googledrive.com/host/*id* where *id* is the file's ID. Inspired by http://www.scriptscoop2.com/t/1eb5579419c6/issue-when-trying-to-stream-a-video-from-google-drive-inside-html5-vid.html.

Comment: That method is deprecated and will stop working in a few months: http://googleappsdeveloper.blogspot.com/2015/08/deprecating-web-hosting-support-in.html

Comment: I don't get why they can't just keep it but not update it.